# Exporting a list of data from Craigslist to CSV

Tags: python, csv, web

I am running the following code in Python to grab a list of items from Craigslist but I want to export the data to a CSV file:

```
import csv

from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path=r"C:\Users\z\Desktop\z\Python\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("http://vancouver.craigslist.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="sss0"]/li[19]/a""").click()
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("hdrlnk")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
```

The code being used to write to csv is shown below but I always get an error:

```
with open("C:\Users\z\Desktop\z\Python\test.csv","wb") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
    for post in posts:
        writer.writerows(posts.text)
```

Error is:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename:   
    C:\Users\z\Desktop\z\Python\test.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"\t" will be interpreted as a tabulation

```
>>> "C:\Users\z\Desktop\z\Python\test.csv"
'C:\\Users\\z\\Desktop\\z\\Python\test.csv'
>>> print _
C:\Users\z\Desktop\z\Python est.csv
>>> "C:\Users\z\Desktop\z\Python\\test.csv"
'C:\\Users\\z\\Desktop\\z\\Python\\test.csv'
>>> print _
C:\Users\z\Desktop\z\Python\test.csv
```

The following should work

```
with open("C:\Users\z\Desktop\z\Python\\test.csv","wb") as output:
```

or

```
with open(r'C:\Users\z\Desktop\z\Python\test.csv',"wb") as output:
```

Comment: Hey WNG. Thanks for your suggestion. But now I got a new error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text' for the field posts. Any idea

Comment: @Sufia You probably want `writer.writerows(post.text)` instead of `writer.writerows(posts.text)`

Comment: Hey @PeterWood. Thanks for your suggestion. My data now downloads to csv! Thank you sir but i get one letter per column is this unusual?

Comment: Hi I answered my own question the key was to use: writer.writerow([post.text])
Put the post.text in square brackets. @PeterWood. Thank you guys!